# Three.js: how to use a plane to cut objects in 2 parts?

Tags: javascript, three.js, clipping

I have a complex object, i.e. a box, and I would like to cut it dynamically. This jsFiddle is a very simple example:[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/jekmp52r/)

**Very simple plane**

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material3 );
plane.rotation.x =1.3; // -Math.PI / 2;
gui.add(plane.rotation, "x", 0.1, Math.PI / 2).name("angle");
gui.add(plane.position, "y", -1, 1).name("h");
scene.add( plane );
```

I would like to remove from my object the upper part. Just like to cut off a piece from an apple using a knife.

The plane is the knife: In my example, you can play with 2 controls to move the plane up and down or change the angle.

[image: example]

Can you help me to hide the removed part from the object?

Comment: To start, see: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two options:

1. You could use [clipping](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping) as WestLangley mentioned above.

   - Clipping does not modify the vertex geometry, it's only visual.
   - Is non-destructive, so it's good for animating or making constant updates.
   - Clipping is mostly done with a few planes instead of complex geometry.
2. You could use a boolean operation with [Constructive Solid Geometry](https://evanw.github.io/csg.js/).

   - Boolean does affect the vertex geometry, which can be exported.
   - Operation is "destructive", so you can't make updates once it's done.
   - Boolean can be performed with complex geometries, as long as they're "manifold".

Boolean operations require both geometries to be [manifold geometries](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) in order to work. This means both meshes have to be closed, without open faces. You cannot use infinitely thin planes, so the example in your JSFiddle wouldn't work. You would need to give each side a little bit of thickness, like using a box with a width of 0.0001 instead of a plane.

Comment: Thanks @Marquizzo!  I'm using option 1 and it looks great. I've just another issue because my main object seems to be "empty" when it is cut off. Do you know if there is an option or setting to "fill" the object section?